# How do I hook into an event triggered by the end of a Brightcove hosted video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, brightcove, appcloud

I have the following code to show a Brightcove player when the user clicks on an image with a play button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#performanceVideo').hide();
    $('#banner_text_wrap').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('banner-image').hide().fadeOut(slow);
        $('#performanceVideo').show().fadeIn(slow).css({'float':'left','margin-top':'-251px'});
    });
});
```

I want to fade the image back in when the video ends. How do I hook into the video end event using jQuery? Reading the documentation I think I would need to include `addEventListener` in the code but I'm a JavaScript novice so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these two parameters to your player snippet:

```
<param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
<param name="templateLoadHandler" value="myTemplateLoaded" />
```

Then add a javascript function that matches the value you gave for the templateLoadHandler in the snippet params to setup an event listener for the videoPlayers end event.

```
function myTemplateLoaded(experienceID){
  player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
  modVP = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
  modVP.addEventListener(brightcove.api.events.MediaEvent.COMPLETE,onMediaComplete);
}
```

Then hide the player when the complete event fires:

```
function onMediaComplete(evt){
  $('#performanceVideo').hide();
  $('banner-image').show().fadeIn(slow);
}
```